# In Gremlin, how to query two or more vertices with same value on one property?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I want to find two or more vertices which have one same property. For example, find two different Person vretices with same name.
I have tried the following:

```
graph.traversal().V().hasLabel("Person").as("a").where("a", P.eq("a")).by("name").where("a", P.neq("a")).by("vid").toList()
```

but the result is null(I am quite sure that there are qualified vertices in the graph.)
[image] 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to scan through the vertices twice. With your current traversal, you only compare each vertex with itself.

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").as("a").
  V().hasLabel("Person").as("b").
  where("a", P.eq("b")).by("name").
  where("a", P.neq("b"))
```